# PIC 18F2550 External Interrupt Problem

Tags: pic, embedded, interrupts

I am working on a basic PIC based circuit to improve myself. What I want to do is to make LED's on one by one, every time I press the push button. I am using external interrupt to do this.However, I am in trouble with the push button which I use at RB0. INT0 external interrupt should occur every time I push the button but it never happens. But I am not sure about it. It might be caused by something else. I will be glad if anyone helps me to solve it. Circuit and codes are below.

```
#include "newheader.h"
#include <pic18f2550.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

int intCount = 0;

void main(void) {
TRISB = 0x01;
TRISC = 0x00;

INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;
INTCONbits.INT0IF=0;
INTCONbits.INT0IE = 1;
INTCONbits.GIE = 1;
INTCON2bits.INTEDG0 = 1;
INTCON2bits.NOT_RBPU = 0;
while(1);

}

void __interrupt() isr(void){
if(INTCONbits.INT0IF==1){
    INTCONbits.GIE = 0;
    __delay_ms (50);
    if (LATBbits.LB0 && intCount == 0){
        __delay_ms (50);
        PORTCbits.RC7 = 1 ;
    }
    if (LATBbits.LB0 && intCount == 1){
        __delay_ms (50);
        PORTCbits.RC6 = 1 ;
    }
    if (LATBbits.LB0 && intCount == 2){
        __delay_ms (50);
        PORTCbits.RC2 = 1 ;
    }
    if (LATBbits.LB0 && intCount == 3){
        __delay_ms (50);
        PORTCbits.RC1 = 1 ;
    }
    if (LATBbits.LB0 && intCount == 4){
        __delay_ms (50);
        PORTCbits.RC0 = 1 ;
    }
    if (LATBbits.LB0 && intCount == 5){
        __delay_ms (50);
        PORTC = 0x00 ;
        intCount = 0;
    }
    INTCONbits.INT0IF=0;
}
intCount++;
}
```

[image: Circuit]

Comment: How and where are you setting your configuration bits? For example, have you disabled the WDT?

Comment: Dear @Pzy I have disabled WDT and LVP. There are also other bits that are disabled but I have disabled only those two.

Comment: Are you using an external clock? Have you set the config bits for the oscillator?

Comment: MCLR is active low. Are you pulling it high?

Comment: The USR doesn't run? But have you confirmed the code runs elsewhere? Beginner code might benefit from setting an output from main just to check the code has run that far.

Comment: Isr (not use - typo)

Comment: Why are you clearing (0) GIE in your ISR? As soon as the ISR is called the GIE bit is cleared. In assembly the final command would be retfie which would set (1) the GIE bit and thus enable all unmasked interrupts. When choosing in c do you need to set GIE at the end of your ISR?

Comment: *coding (not "choosing"). I'll make this the last time I use mobile phone to comment.

Comment: I am using external clock "XT" and I have set its config bit. I am feeding MCLR pin with Vcc (5V). ISR seems running when I use the XC8 debugger. I followed the code through debugging . When RB0 pin goes 1, interrupt begins and the PORTC pins set just like it should be but in Proteus it doesn't happen. I am clearing GIE to avoid any other interrupts.

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? `if (LATBbits.LB0 &&`

Comment: @BruceAbbott It checks if both the button (RB0) is pushed and how many interrupts have occured so far. For example Let's assume  2 interrupts have occured,when I push the button again , third interrupt will occur and the related LED will turn on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIC18F I/O ports have a Latch register for output, and a PORT register for input. Writing to the PORT address writes to the Latch register.

Diagram from [PIC18F2550](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/PIC18F2550) datasheet)

[image]

To test a pin state you must read the PORT register. Therefore to read the state of the button you should change each occurrence of `LATBbits.LB0` to `PORTBbits.RB0`.

Writing to PORT bits is OK, just realize that to write an individual bit the MCU must first read the PORT register, then change the bit, and finally write the result back to the register (this is called a 'read modify write' operation). If any pins *other* than the one you are modifying are being forced low or high by external circuitry (eg. Base of a transistor or a 'large' capacitor) then the corresponding Latch bits will be set to the *pin* values, overriding what was previously in the Latch. This can cause output bits to flip unexpectedly. To ensure that output bits do not get disturbed it is best to reference the Latch register when manipulating bits, eg. `LATCbits.LC7 = 1`.